# Does SQL Server support a feature to track audit, BOTH row update and schema changes in the same place

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, audit, change-data-capture

I currently capture audit history of billing changes tables data in a SQL Server database, on the row updates/inserts. This question/answer has been beaten to death (but also evolved both from Microsoft SQL Server features, and features for user defined solutions).

However, I am finding in my scenario, frequent schema changes. So, I am manually dropping and recreating the shadow audit tables, which is getting tedious over many tables.

Is there turn-key feature or plugin with SQL Server that does both with ease from dev perspective/non-dba, i.e. capture both the meta changes and full row update/transaction, in the same place / one stop shopping?

There seem to be a many ways, but I want one solution the. The way I do this now, is I add a new column to the shadow table as the schema grows, and look for when the schema was changed in the audit table.

1. CDC - Change Data Capture, but drops the tables on cleanup
2. Audit Triggers
3. Audit Table Feature
4. [AutoAudit](http://bit.ly/1PRw5W0): love the options , not updated, performance seems slow
5. [EF Audit tracking](http://bit.ly/1SDb1Do) changes change tracking

Comment: "Does SQL server support a feature to track audit, BOTH row update and schema changes in the same place" - No. And it shouldn't!  Schema changes should be scripted and under some form of source control.

Comment: @MitchWheat thanks, so capturing the schema changes *to* a table *in* a table is not possible then? if thats right, then I can close it out as answer. We already have Source control, but looking to capture the schema changes in the DB

Comment: Everything is possible, I just don't think it's the right place for schema chnages